# how to add self defined header for document class book?

Tags: header-footer

I am using document class called book.It takes the default section name and chapter name as header.but i want my header to be the name of my project. Please help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please consider adding a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to help us help you.

Comment: Also, use `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `titleps` from the `titlesec` bundle. With this code in your preamble, for instance:

```
\usepackage{titleps}
   \newpagestyle{mine}{%
\   titlerule
\sethead{}{\scshape\small My nice project}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}%
\pagestyle{mine}
```

You will have a centred header in `smallcaps` and `small` size, with a header rule, and centred page number in the footer.